# setting a select option by another select selected option

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to built 3 selects that when u set the Month select, the days in the Day select will change according to the month

html:

```
<select id="Day" name="Day">
</select>
<select id="Month" name="Month" onchange="monthSelected()">
</select>
<select id="Year" name="Year">
</select>
```

and on pageload:

```
<body onload ="addDate()">
```

the script:

onDate():

```
function addDate() {
        addMonth();
        addYear();
        addDay(1);
    } //addDate
```

the adds functions:

```
function addYear() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var legalWorkingAge = currentYear - 16;
    var select = document.getElementById("Year");
    for (var i = legalWorkingAge; i >= 1900; i--) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
        }//for
} //addYear
function addMonth() {
    var select = document.getElementById("Month");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    } //for
} //addMonth
function addDay(month) {
    var select = document.getElementById("Day");
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        select.options[i] = null;
    }
    var daynum;
    switch (month) {
        case 1: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 2: daynum = 28;
            break;
        case 3: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 4: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 5: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 6: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 7: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 8: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 9: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 10: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 11: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 12: daynum = 31;
            break;
    }//switch
        for (var i = 1; i <= daynum; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    } //for
} //addDay
```

the monthSelceted function(when you change the select"Month"):

```
function monthSelected() {
    var month = document.getElementById("Month");
    var selectedMonth = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
    addDay(selectedMonth);
}
```

here is what it does: http://jsfiddle.net/pMUY3/6/
i have no idea why

how do i fix it? Tnx for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong here

1. Before the switch statement, convert the `month` to an int like this

   month = parseInt(month);
2. When you remove the options, do not increase `i`, because when you remove the `i`-th option, the next option shifts downwards and is skipped, when you increase `i`. Instead, remove option 0 until the array is empty. You can do it like this:

   for (var i = 0; select.options.length > 0;) {
               select.options[i] = null;
           }

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple bugs in this code.

First, your `for` loop at the beginning of `addDay` isn't removing all the options. When you remove one, it decreases the length of the array of options by one, and at the same time increments the counter, `i`, by one, so it skips every other option. This results in the behavior you are seeing, where each time a month is selected, every other day is removed from the day list.

Fix this by doing the following instead of that `for` loop:

```
while (select.options.length > 0) {
    select.options[0] = null;
}
```

Second, your `switch` statement is never being entered, so `daynum` is always `undefined`, so no new options are ever added. It isn't entered because `month` is a string, while the cases are all numbers. This is easily fixed by changing `month` to an integer, using `parseInt`:

```
switch (parseInt(month)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your addDay to this :

```
function addDay(month) {

        /***** cast is needed to matching month value with you case statements ******/
        month = parseInt(month); 
        /***** cast is needed to matching month value with you case statements ******/



        var select = document.getElementById("Day");




        /*********** for statement needs to replace with this ***********/
        while (select.options.length != 0)
        {
            select.options.remove(0);
        }
        /*********** for statement needs to replace with this ***********/




        var daynum;
        switch (month) {
            case 1: daynum = 31;
                break;
            case 2: daynum = 28;
                break;
            case 3: daynum = 31;
                break;
            case 4: daynum = 30;
                break;
            case 5: daynum = 31;
                break;
            case 6: daynum = 30;
                break;
            case 7: daynum = 31;
                break;
            case 8: daynum = 31;
                break;
            case 9: daynum = 30;
                break;
            case 10: daynum = 31;
                break;
            case 11: daynum = 30;
                break;
            case 12: daynum = 31;
                break;
        }//switch
        for (var i = 1; i <= daynum; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = option.value = i;
            select.add(option, 0);
        } //for
    } //addDay
```